# swift activityIndicater is not remove after completing data loading from web

Tags: swift, tableview

I made infinite-scrolling in tableView, it works very well but the problem is `activityIndicator` do not hide when complete data loading.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: footerCellid) as! HeadFooterCell

    if !isInitUILoad {    
        tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = true

        loadMore(complition: { (isDone) in
            self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
        })
    }
    return footerView
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {       
    return 0.01
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let lastSectionIndex = tableView.numberOfSections - 1
    let lastRowIndex = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: lastSectionIndex) - 1
    if indexPath.section ==  lastSectionIndex && indexPath.row == lastRowIndex {
        // print("this is the last cell")
        let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
        spinner.startAnimating()
        spinner.backgroundColor = .green
        spinner.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: tableView.bounds.width, height: CGFloat(44))

        self.tableView.tableFooterView = spinner
        self.tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `activityIndicatorView.hidesWhenStopped` set to true?

Comment: @DávidPásztor which i have to put this code please tell me

Comment: Where are you setting up your `activityIndicatorView`? Set the property there. If you are adding it from `Storyboard`, put `activityIndicatorView.hidesWhenStopped = true` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor it is not working

Comment: Make sure loadMore completion block runs in the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at first of all you have to delete this two function "viewForFooterInSection" and "heightForFooterInSection". next you have to add "willDisplay" function. hope to solve your problem after use this code

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

**willDisplay**

```
    let lastSectionIndex = tableView.numberOfSections - 1
    let lastRowIndex = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: lastSectionIndex) - 1
    if indexPath.section ==  lastSectionIndex && indexPath.row == lastRowIndex {

        let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
        spinner.backgroundColor = .yellow


        spinner.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: tableView.bounds.width, height: CGFloat(50))

        self.tableView.tableFooterView = spinner
       self.tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = false


        if !isInitUILoad {

            spinner.startAnimating()

            loadMore(complition: { (isDone) in

                spinner.stopAnimating()


            })


        }

    }

}
```